# C - quando uso o local.h o scanf não funciona bem

Tags: c, acentuação, ascii, caracteres, locale

Estou a criar uma base de dados.

Usei o `locale.h` e `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese")` para que acentos e cedilhas apareçam na linha de comandos do windows.

Devido a isto quando faço um `scanf` de um caractere com acento ou cedilhado e faço o respectivo `printf` ele imprime um símbolo inexistente no alfabeto e o valor correspondente em decimal é um numero negativo.

Se o caractere especial não for introduzido por scanf (ou fgets) e já tiver no código o programa 'imprime-o' normalmente

Já fiz alguma pesquisa no assunto e encontrei muita informação sobre os vários tipos de codificação e unicode mas nada sobre o porque disto acontecer.

Deixo o meu código:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <locale.h>

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese") ;

    /* Para ver a tabela ASCII */

    int x ;

    for(x = 0; x <= 255; x++) {

        printf("[%d]: %c\n", x, x);
    }

    char ch ;

    printf("Introduzir caractere: ")
    scanf("%c", &ch) ;
    printf("Caractere introduzido: %c\n", ch);
    printf("Valor na tabela ASCII: %d\n", ch);
}
```

introduzindo, por exemplo, um "ç" o caractere que imprime é "╬" e o valor em decimal é -121. O mesmo acontece com outros caracteres com acento.

Porque é que isto está a acontecer?

Comment: Aqui sem o `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");` funcionou normalmente para ler e exibir o `ç`. Já quando colocado, acontece a mesma coisa: `╬`.

Comment: O decimal é -121 porque está a ser visto como `char` em vez de `unsigned char`. Está a testar direto na consola ou a correr em algum IDE ?

Comment: Mas mesmo usando unsigned char ele assume o mesmo simbolo...
Estou a usar o Code Blocks.

Comment: Confirme que tem o CodeBlocks a funcionar com o encoding correto, para alem de utilizar o `setlocale` como já foi mencionado nos comentários